# An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred - MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

this is my stack trace .. i get this bug when i debug the code.How to solve this  'System.AccessViolationException'  issue ? i m using Visual studio 2010 and visual c++ MFC code.

'UROC GUI.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110_clr0400.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'UROC GUI.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\ce5f61c5754789df97be8dc991c47d07\mscorlib.ni.dll', No native symbols in symbol file.
'UROC GUI.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'UROC GUI.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\ZC440Z0rr1\Desktop\UROC 11 alpha 6\UROC Software\Release\UROC GUI.exe', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'UROC GUI.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
First-chance exception at 0x522fa208 (mfc100u.dll) in UROC GUI.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000006c.
'UROC GUI.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in UROC GUI.exe

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: It looks like you program is a mixed mode program, i.e. it uses some .Net stuff. Most likely a .Net dll it is referenced to is missing

Comment: Have you tried running this under Microsoft's tool Application Verifier?

Comment: no i didnt verfiy using that ..